# COUNT UNION too many

Tags: mysql, sql, count, duplicates, union

So... I have a query that returns user accounts that have been made in my website with the same email address, password and other info (yeah, bad implementation, don't ask). It does so by being fed the user id from another program.

My SQL is

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT usuario.id as 'user_id',
          concat(usuario.nombre, ' ', usuario.apellidos) AS 'user_full_name',
          usuario.email 'user_email',
                        LEFT(usuario.date_created, 19) AS 'user_date_created',
                        LEFT(usuario.last_updated, 19) AS 'user_last_updated',
                        CASE
                            WHEN usuario.status = 10 THEN 'Banned'
                            ELSE 'Active'
                        END AS 'status',
                        'Mismos datos' AS duplicate_type,
                        CASE
                            WHEN usuario.es_broker=0 THEN 'Consumer'
                            WHEN usuario.es_tm=1 THEN 'TM'
                            ELSE 'Broker'
                        END AS 'user_type',
                        COUNT(DISTINCT penalizacion.id) AS 'penalty_count'
   FROM usuario
   JOIN penalizacion ON usuario.id = penalizacion.vendedor_id
   WHERE usuario.password =
       (SELECT usuario.password
        FROM usuario
        WHERE usuario.id = {USUARIO_DUPE})
   UNION SELECT usuario.id as 'user_id',
                concat(usuario.nombre, ' ', usuario.apellidos),
                usuario.email,
                LEFT(usuario.date_created, 19),
                LEFT(usuario.last_updated, 19),
                CASE
                    WHEN usuario.status = 10 THEN 'Dado de baja'
                    ELSE 'Activo'
                END AS 'status',
                'Mismo móvil' AS duplicate_type,
                CASE
                    WHEN usuario.es_broker=0 THEN 'Consumer'
                    WHEN usuario.es_tm=1 THEN 'TM'
                    ELSE 'Broker'
                END AS 'user_type',
                COUNT(DISTINCT penalizacion.id) AS 'penalty_count'
   FROM usuario
   JOIN penalizacion ON usuario.id = penalizacion.vendedor_id
   WHERE usuario.numero_movil =
       (SELECT usuario.numero_movil
        FROM usuario
        WHERE usuario.id = {USUARIO_DUPE})
   UNION SELECT usuario.id as 'user_id',
                concat(usuario.nombre, ' ', usuario.apellidos),
                usuario.email,
                LEFT(usuario.date_created, 19),
                LEFT(usuario.last_updated, 19),
                CASE
                    WHEN usuario.status = 10 THEN 'Dado de baja'
                    ELSE 'Activo'
                END AS 'status',
                'Mismo email' AS duplicate_type,
                CASE
                    WHEN usuario.es_broker=0 THEN 'Consumer'
                    WHEN usuario.es_tm=1 THEN 'TM'
                    ELSE 'Broker'
                END AS 'user_type',
                COUNT(DISTINCT penalizacion.id) AS 'penalty_count'
   FROM usuario
   JOIN penalizacion ON usuario.id = penalizacion.vendedor_id
   WHERE usuario.email =
       (SELECT usuario.email
        FROM usuario
        WHERE usuario.id = {USUARIO_DUPE})
   UNION SELECT usuario.id,
                concat(usuario.nombre, ' ', usuario.apellidos),
                usuario.email,
                LEFT(usuario.date_created, 19),
                LEFT(usuario.last_updated, 19),
                CASE
                    WHEN usuario.status = 10 THEN 'Dado de baja'
                    ELSE 'Activo'
                END AS 'status',
                'Misma tarjeta principal' AS duplicate_type,
                CASE
                    WHEN usuario.es_broker=0 THEN 'Consumer'
                    WHEN usuario.es_tm=1 THEN 'TM'
                    ELSE 'Broker'
                END AS 'user_type',
                COUNT(DISTINCT penalizacion.id) AS 'penalty_count'
   FROM usuario
   JOIN penalizacion ON usuario.id = penalizacion.vendedor_id
   WHERE usuario.main_credit_card_id =
       (SELECT usuario.main_credit_card_id
        FROM usuario
        WHERE usuario.id = {USUARIO_DUPE})
   ORDER BY status DESC) A
GROUP BY user_id
```

You'll notice that I have a column that tries to count how many penalties each of these duplicate user accounts have. However, instead of that, the "penalty_count" column seems to sum the number of penalties of the id of the user whose duplicates I am looking for AND the number of penalties of the actual duplicate.

So instead of getting

[image: COUNT counts too much when UNIONing]

I get this

[image: wished result of COUNT is ok]

Comment: Too big problem. Minimize it!

Comment: Agreed with jarlh. Your SQL query is way too big for your problem to be resolved by someone else. Try to minimize to the minimum problem (i.e: Trying to get number of occurrences for same user email)

Comment: Where are your GROUP BY clauses within your UNION queries? Pull one out and run it on it's own to see what it's doing. By the looks of it you may be effectively putting in 1 for each row rather than each distinct value. It's tough to tell without seeing your data though.

Comment: Whoa! We've seen queries. That's a **QUERY**!  Far too large for strangers unfamiliar with your system to try to parse!  May I suggest you find an online tool to format, or prettyprint, this SQL, then you examine it carefully? May I also suggest you try to eliminate the dependent subqueries ( ` ... WHERE something IN (SELECT something FROM ....` ) and replace them with JOINs?  Finally, troubleshoot by breaking up your query into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the comments. I don't know what I was thinking. I'll try to identify the problem and then ask again with a more concise question! Thanks!